# Change a set NSLayoutConstraint programmatically later

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I'm creating a View in code (no xib or storyboard for this one) and setting the constraints in code, like:

```
NSDictionary *bindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_myView);
_myView = [[UIView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:_myView];
_myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[_myView]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings ] ];
[self.view addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[_myView(25)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:bindings ] ];
```

Later in another method I want to change the position of `_myView` and animate this changing.

My problem:
What is the best/correct way to change the set constraints?
I don't know how to change e.g. the X and Y poisition. E.g. I set both values to 0 and I want to change X and Y to 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints are like any other object, if you want to change them later make a property.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *centerConstraint;
```

Then set it to a particular constraint, add it to the view and you can remove and re-add it later.

Comment: OK thanks. Is it the only appropriate way? When I have e.g. 10 UIViews with 2 constraints per view that I want to change then I have to define 20 constraint properties...

Comment: You could use a property which is an array of constraints and add and remove with `-addConstraints:` etc. You could hide the adding in a method and call that. Either way, Auto Layout is just verbose.